# Set value based on previous value in previous group if it exists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have this:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(
  [ dict(a=75, b=numpy.nan, d='2023-01-01 00:00')
  , dict(a=82, b=numpy.nan, d='2023-01-01 10:00')
  , dict(a=39, b=numpy.nan, d='2023-01-01 20:00')
  , dict(a=10, b=82       , d='2023-01-05 00:00')
  , dict(a=90, b=82       , d='2023-01-05 20:00')
  , dict(a=61, b=numpy.nan, d='2023-02-08 00:00')
  , dict(a=35, b=numpy.nan, d='2023-02-08 10:00')
  , dict(a=95, b=numpy.nan, d='2023-02-08 20:00')
  , dict(a=21, b=35       , d='2023-04-15 00:00')
  , dict(a=60, b=35       , d='2023-04-15 10:00')
  ])                                             
df['d'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['d'])            
df = df.set_index('d')                           
print(df)
```

which outputs:

```
                      a     b
d
2023-01-01 00:00:00  75   NaN
2023-01-01 10:00:00  82   NaN
2023-01-01 20:00:00  39   NaN
2023-01-05 00:00:00  10  82.0
2023-01-05 20:00:00  90  82.0
2023-02-08 00:00:00  61   NaN
2023-02-08 10:00:00  35   NaN
2023-02-08 20:00:00  95   NaN
2023-04-15 00:00:00  21  35.0
2023-04-15 10:00:00  60  35.0
```

In real life, I only have column `a` and my desired output is in column `b`.

Here, `b` equals the value in `a` from the previous available date at 10:00. Dates are not necessarily consecutive. Value at 10:00 may not exist for the previous available date, in which case `b` should be NaN.

Logically, I'd solve this by grouping by date and extracting the value from the previous group.

Without resorting to iterating each `(previous group, group)` tuples or something of sorts, can that be done with pandas?

More generally, are there any pandas idioms to deal with these "look up value from the previous group" situations?

---

I'll be adding edits here as answers come to show additional info that doesn't fit nicely in a comment.

For https://stackoverflow.com/a/75599866/3821009

```
df['c'] = df.groupby(df.index.date)['a'].shift() 
print(df)
```

produces:

```
                      a     b     c
d
2023-01-01 00:00:00  75   NaN   NaN
2023-01-01 10:00:00  82   NaN  75.0
2023-01-01 20:00:00  39   NaN  82.0
2023-01-05 00:00:00  10  82.0   NaN
2023-01-05 20:00:00  90  82.0  10.0
2023-02-08 00:00:00  61   NaN   NaN
2023-02-08 10:00:00  35   NaN  61.0
2023-02-08 20:00:00  95   NaN  35.0
2023-04-15 00:00:00  21  35.0   NaN
2023-04-15 10:00:00  60  35.0  21.0
```

so that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hi, Hope this can help to resolve your issue [pandas.DataFrame.itertuples](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html), example: `df.itertuples()`

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh the desired output is in column `b`. I'm just trying to see how to do that based on column `a` without iteration. Le me edit the question to clarify that.

Comment: @UtkarshDubey Yeah I mentioned that as a last resort, but I'm trying to avoid iterating though since that's slow.